# javascript/jquery - check focus of input[type='search']?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying this:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='search']").on("focus", function(e, ui) {
    $("[data-role='footer']").hide();
    console.log('focus');
});
```

I'd expect it to log when I focus on a search field but that seems to not be the case. Works fine when I focus on a text field. I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery so maybe I'm just being dumb about something. Did some Googling but didn't find anything helpful.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RDz2J/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine after fixing a syntax error. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RDz2J/5/. What browsers are you testing this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, all that you were missing was an extra `)` to close the function properly.

It works now and saves `Got it` in a div, I removed alert as it forced me to close the browser as a whole :( Sorry.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/RDz2J/4/

And also try to shorten down the code as:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='search']").focus(function() {
    $("[data-role='footer']").hide();
    console.log('focus');
});
```

I have removed the `e, ui` since you're not using it in the code and have changed the `on` event to `focus` directly.

Comment: Okay well that's awkward. The syntax error doesn't exist in the code I pasted into my question, and it still doesn't work. It's not throwing any errors to the log, either. Any ideas there?

Comment: For that the only guess of mine would be, are you using `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code here.. */ })` ?? Since the code is perfect..@Rob

Comment: Yeah. I don't know, I reckon I'll just play with it a bit until I figure it out. I've been tasked with fixing another dev's code (he just recently quit) and it's just a pain in the ass the way he handled everything. There's probably some bug further down in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You had a simple syntax error; you had not added an extra end paranthesis. 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RDz2J/6/) is an updated fiddle, and here is the new code

```
$("input[type='search']").on("focus", function (e, ui) {
    alert('got it!');
});
```